# Two columns figure using subfloat

Tags: floats, subfloats, ieeetran

I am trying to make a two column figure of set of subfigures using `subfloat`. My problem is that the figure appears in one column only and 
the rest of the figure is not displayed as shown in the following figure

[image]

this is my code :

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfloat}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
   \centering
   \subfloat[Tree-2]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{img1.png}}\label{img1}
   \subfloat[Tree-4]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{img2.png}}\label{img2}\\
   \subfloat[Tree-6]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{img3.png}}\label{img3}
   \subfloat[Tree-10]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{img4.png}}\label{img4}\\
   \subfloat[Tree-15]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{img5.png}}\label{img5}
   \subfloat[Tree-20]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{img6.png}}\label{img6}\\
   \caption{confusion matrix.}
   \label{fig:confusion}
   \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please make your code complete. `\documentclass...\end{document}`

Comment: Maybe your figure is just too wide? If two figures do not fit next to each other in one row on a page, there will be a line break between them. Maybe you can use landscape paper format, or you can scale the figures to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to my above comment:

If you use a double-column format like `IEEEtran`, you might want to use the `figure*` environment instead of the `figure` environment. `figure` only occupies one column. `figure*` spans both.

Comment: But, whenever i use figure* the figure disappears

Comment: It should have just moved.  figure* can only use t,b and p, not h.

Comment: @ahmedabobakr Using the code in your question (adding a `\begin{document}`), and changing from `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` to `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}` I get a figure spanning two columns.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yup thanks, It sounds like I have a problem with my Latex compiler, because, I tested it on another machine and it works well.